# Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError in Neo4j In HTTP API

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I used the Cypher query which contains escape character (\) which I replaced with \\ , which is working perfectly fine Neo4j browser but the same query showing exception like

> "Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError","message":"Invalid input 'B':
>   expected '\', ''', '\"', 'b', 'f', 'n', 'r', 't', UTF16 or UTF32" in
>   Neo4j HTTP API.

Cypher query which I used in Neo4j browser:

```
MERGE (senderpaymentinstrument:PAYMENTINSTRUMENT{PYMTINSTID:'fOL'}) ON 
CREATE SET senderpaymentinstrument.BANKNAME = 'D\\\\B\\\\A BONNEVILLE 
BANK',senderpaymentinstrument.PYMTINSTTYPE = 'CREDIT_CARD'
```

In HTTP API I used endpoint http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit
and My JSON post looks like the following:

```
{"statements" : [
        {"statement" : "MERGE (senderpaymentinstrument:PAYMENTINSTRUMENT{PYMTINSTID:'fOL'}) ON CREATE SET senderpaymentinstrument.BANKNAME = 'D\\\\B\\\\A BONNEVILLE BANK',senderpaymentinstrument.PYMTINSTTYPE = 'CREDIT_CARD'"}
    ]
}
```

I don't understand what I am missing.

Comment: Why are you using backslashes in the first place? Isn't the "doing business as" abbreviation supposed to be "D/B/A"? Alternatively, you could just use "DBA".

Comment: As it is part of the requirement, as I have to backslashes like D\B\A, and I also replaced it with it '\\', still it shows the same exception throw HTTP API but the same cypher working fine Neo4j browser.It seems very mysterious.

Comment: Have u find the solution please ? Iam facing the same issue to load csv file with absolute path

Comment: @G.Adnane,  I figured out it is an issue with rest call. Whenever you want to insert "\" in cypher, at that time you have to replace it with "\\", These replacements not required when you try to execute the cypher through the browser.